# Check value extracted with JSONPath and compare with regex using Gatling

Tags: regex, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Is there a way of doing something like this in Gatling:

```
scenario("Check UUID with regex")
      .exec(http("Get UUID")
      .get("http://myapp/api/v1/goal/a24e210c-0fc1-44a0-a5ca-9bd5d8d71916")        
      .check(jsonPath("$.id").is(regex("[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}")))
```

Basically I want to apply a regex comparison on something returned in a check JSONPath construct.

Peace out!

P.S. I know I can do:
`.check(regex("\"id\": \"[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\"").exists)`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing quite like what you describe, but you can kind of fake it using a transform

```
.check(jsonPath("$.id")
    .find
    .transform(id => "[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}".r
                 .findFirstMatchIn(id) match {
                    case Some(value) => true
                    case None => false                     
                  }
     ).is(true)
```

but if the straight regex check works... I'd go with that

Comment: There is the validate method that allows the user to pass in arbitrary code.
`def validate(opName: String, validator: (Option[X], Session) => Validation[Option[X]])`